# Is it possible to debug ASHX handler using IIS Express in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, ashx

I have a web application project in Visual Studio 2012 Express which makes ajax requests against some generic handlers, ASHX files.  I can step through the javascript code when I use `Debug->Start Debugging` menu option. But is it also possible to set breakpoints in the C# code and step through that code as well, using IISExpress?